# How to access kernel documentation with texdoc?

Tags: texdoc

Sorry if that is dumb, but fumbling with `\ProcessKeysOptions` and `\ProcessKeyOptions`, I read in the documentation of the former that it was obsoleted by the latter, which is integrated into the LaTeX kernel. But, for that precise reason, I cannot find its documentation.

When a command comes from a package, it suffices to run `texdoc name-of-package`, but `texdoc kernel` and `texdoc latex` do not give meaningful results on my texlive 2023.

Comment: texdoc clsguide for top level description texdoc source2e for sources